# Is it possible to call the PayPal REST API and request it to stop an active user payment with a certain PAYID?

Tags: paypal

My server allows users to pay via PayPal for services. I am concerned that they could potentially click pay, then go to my web address on another browser (same account) and click pay whilst they have the PayPal widget open on the other browser. Ultimately allowing them to pay twice for one item. Can I therefore call the PayPal rest API when the user clicks the pay button on my site and tell PayPal to terminate any active transactions? (I have the ID's of any active transactions for each user as part of my logging function, so it would be easy for me to pass these to PayPal to tell it to stop them)

Answer (score 0):

No to your specific question, but the way to achieve this is to specify a unique `invoice_id` (typically your own system/business' own unique order #) when setting up the payment -- such as with a [v2/checkout/orders create](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) call that will be approved with [the JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). (ed: since you mention PAYIDs it seem you're referencing the deprecated v1/payments API. This should not be used for new integrations, but it does have an equivalent invoice number field)

By default a PayPal account can only receive payments for a specific invoice_id once; after the first payment for a given invoice_id completes *successfully*, repeat payments for that same ID to that account will be blocked from capture with a DUPLICATE_INVOICE_ID error. The feature exists for exactly the scenario you describe, to prevent accidental repeat payment for the same thing.